# Firebase deploy but not showing my website

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Hi I have completed the `firebase init` and `firebase deploy --only hosting`. It shown the successful modal message of

"Welcome
Firebase Hosting Setup Complete

You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!"

But it does not show my website however.

I have tried Firefox and IE Edge but still shows the same message.

Please see my firebase.json file:

```js
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/cook4u",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "eventarc": {
      "port": 9299
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "remoteconfig": {
    "template": "remoteconfig.template.json"
  }
}
```

I have tried the solutions in stackoverflow and other websites. It does not solve my problem. I have confirmed that my index.html and all my source code is in my public folder. Also, how to determine which page is the landing page of my website?

Here is my public folder. Is there anything I am missing?

[image: public folder screenshot]

Dist folder screenshot:

[dist folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOjGo.jpg)

[cook4u folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHrSd.jpg)

Here is the output when I run the deploy command:

- hosting[cook4u-b3b8d]: file upload complete
  i  hosting[cook4u-b3b8d]: finalizing version...
- hosting[cook4u-b3b8d]: version finalized
  i  hosting[cook4u-b3b8d]: releasing new version...
- hosting[cook4u-b3b8d]: release complete
  i  hosting[cook4u-b3b8d]: beginning deploy...
- Deploy complete!3b8d]: found 119 files in public

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/cook4u-b3b8d/overview
Hosting URL: https://cook4u-b3b8d.web.app

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of `dist` folder?

Comment: @Dharmaraj no problem. edited post with added screenshots.

Comment: The config looks fine to me. What was the output when you run deploy command? Also have you tried accessing the URL from any other browser or device just in case its cached for you?

Comment: @Dharmaraj also posted here for you.

Comment: Thanks for the details. That just seems like initializing Firebase project. Did you try deploying by running `firebase deploy --only hosting`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj apologies, just revised the output for `firebase deploy --only hosting`. It is also shown in my firebase console as "current" in release history.

Comment: Why are there PHP files in your uploaded directory? Unless something changed recently, Firebase Hosting is static and doesn't handle PHP. Additionally your rewrites make every page fall back to `index.html` which may be causing more issues.

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks for pointing out. I was actually coding for mysql all the time. I then decided to host on firebase. I did not know they do not support php. What shall I do in this case? Do I have to recode everything all over?

Comment: If you want to continue using Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions, for long term maintainability, you should rebuild your project following the conventions of the JavaScript language rather than feed it to some PHP conversion tool. If you want to keep using PHP, you'll have to do some research as I am not familiar with any PHP hosts because I haven't used that language in over a decade at this point.

Answer (score 0):

delete your .firebase file

1. firebase init
2. Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? (y/N) n

use no this change your index.html file